# Need help writing a code that checks if a date has been entered in the access database or not C#

Tags: c#

I'm building a booking system for a hotel in C# and one of the requirements is to check if the date the customer chose for check-in from the DateTimePicker is already taken or not. This is the code I found online but it gives me errors

> `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Check-in date= '1/12/2022''.'`

code:

```cs
cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from tbl_booking where Check-in date= '" + this.checkin.Text + "'", con);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
int i = ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count;

if(i > 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Date already taken!", "Date not available", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

I've also posted the db image
[Image showing tbl_booking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Bxl.png)

Comment: Use parameters with the appropriate datatype and do not let the automatic conversion of a string to a date used to represent your value to the database

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: By the way _Check-in date_ is not a valid field name in Jet SQL (and perhaps in any other database system). If  your field has been defined with a space then you need to always use _[field name with spaces]_ syntax

Comment: also: `Check-in date` is _not_ a valid column name.. if your column really is named that way, you have to enclose that string (depending on the SQL dialect in use). but it is general best practice ***not*** to have spaces in column names. (voting to close since this falls under "typo")

Comment: Avoid using any chars other than A-Z in a column name. `CheckInDate` would be better than `Check-in Date`

Comment: I would highly recommend using a real database rather than Access. In my experience Access is slow, unreliable, are limited to 2Gb, need frequent compaction etc. There are many other alternatives that should be a better fit for almost any possible usage scenario.

Comment: Indeed, SqLite is highly preferable to Access, and it's free, and file based so in most respects, like using Access but a lot more like an industry standard DB (SQLS, Oracle, Postgres, MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest route with your current approach is:

- Rename `Check-in date` to `CheckInDate`. Straighten out any other similar problems. These are variable names meaningful only to code, they do not need to be "human friendly"
- Have code:

```
var someDate = new DateTime(2022,2,12);

using var con = new OleDbConnection("conn string here");
using var cmd = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) from tbl_booking where CheckInDate = @cid", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", someDate);
con.Open();
var r = (int)(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

if(r > 0){
  ...
}
```

Don't use a dataadapter for a query that emits a single value; it's a sledgehammer to crack a nut

---

You can make your life somewhat easier by:

- adding a DataSet type file to your project,
- open it, add a tableadapter to its surface,
- configure the connection string. Read closely the long, wordy information message that appears; it is saying if you choose to copy the database file into the project, you must understand that VS will copy it out to the bin/debug folder every time you run - the running app will edit this copy database; a common hiccup with file DBs is that your app writes into `c:\projects\myapp\bin\debug\the.mdb` but you carry on thinking your DB is in `c:\users\you\documents\the.mdb` and you're wondering "why isn't the data I just inserted, visible?" (because you're looking in the wrong file) or "why every time I start my app, is the data gone?" (because the build process copies `c:\projects\myapp\the.mdb -> c:\projects\myapp\bin\debug\the.mdb` overwiting every time)
- choose "query that returns a single value", put the sql above, name the query nicely like CountBookingsOnDate, finish the wizard
- have a code like:

```
  var ta = new QUeriesTableAdapter();
  if(ta.CountBookingsOnDate(soemDate) > 0)
    ...
```

Comment: I followed your instructions but I'm getting a syntax error. https://imgur.com/jlC3bt6

Comment: You're simply using an old version of C# that doesn't support `using var`. Switch it to normal `using(var ... = ...){` blocks or follow the advice underneath  the horizontal line - it'll make your life easier